# `sed` substitude and append to the same line

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I would like to substitute the dots of file by underscores and append the original line to the substituted one with colon.

So, for example I have

```
source.uid
source.ip
source.labels
source.name
...
```

I want to end up with:

```
source_uid: source.uid
source_ip: source.ip
source_labels: source.labels
source_name: source.name
...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one-liner works for the given example:

```
sed 's/.*/&: &/;s/\./_/' file
```

#### Test:

```
kent$  cat f
source.uid
source.ip
source.labels
source.name

kent$  sed 's/.*/&: &/;s/\./_/' f
source_uid: source.uid
source_ip: source.ip
source_labels: source.labels
source_name: source.name
```

an alternative awk one-liner that does the same:

```
awk '{a=$0;gsub(/[.]/,"_",a)}$0=a": "$0' file
```

#### update

If the original line has more dots ("."), the above awk one-liner should work. Also this sed line:

```
sed -n 'h;y/./_/;G;s/\n/: /;p' file
```

Test with a string:

```
kent$  sed -n 'h;y/./_/;G;s/\n/: /;p' <<<"a.b.c.foo.bar" 
a_b_c_foo_bar: a.b.c.foo.bar
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working, but looks like in my question I didn't cover everything. Some attributes have 2 levels (e.g. `destination.workload.namespace`). With this command I get `destination_workload.namespace: destination.workload.namespace`. I would like to get `destination_workload_namespace: destination.workload.namespace`. Sorry about that. Should have though about it.

Comment: @suren that's why I wrote "works for the given example", I added **update** section in the answer. pls check it again.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** To cover all occurrences try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=": "}{val=$0;gsub(/\./,"_");print val,$0;val=""}' Input_file
```

For OP's provided samples output will be as follows:

```
destination.workload.namespace: destination_workload_namespace
```

Explanation:

```
awk '              ##starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{             ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  OFS=": "         ##setting OFS as colon space here.
}
{
  val=$0           ##creating variable val whose value is current line value.
  gsub(/\./,"_")   ##globally substituting dot with underscore.
  print val,$0     ##printing variable val and edited line here.
  val=""           ##Nullify Val here.
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=".";OFS=": "} {print $1"_"$2,$0}' Input_file
```

---

---

Using `sed`: using sed capability of storing matched regex value into temp buffer and later use them as per need.

```
sed 's/\([^.]*\)\.\(.*\)/\1_\2: \1.\2/' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks. this is working too, but I make a mistake in the question; as commented under Kent's answer. You think it's possible to make the change?

Comment: @suren, Kindly try my EDIT one and lemme know then please.

Comment: @suren, I have added detailed explanation in my answer for understanding.